# How should i add header to HTTP GET request using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-get

Trying to add header in the request

```
email = "blahblah@gmail.com"
token = "abcdefghijk"
url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/request?params1=value1&params2=value2"

uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).start
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request['email'] = email
request['token'] = token

response = http.request(request)

render json: response.body
```

The results i have gotten back is `{"error":"invalid request parameters"}`

I am supposed to get back a list of data in json. I tried using postman to test if the url is working and passed the email and token inside header and i got back the data that i wanted. 
I am not sure where it went wrong with the code. Can anybody advise me which part did i do wrongly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to use https://requestb.in/ to check the format of the request. It's possible you are sending malformed data or you are missing some header.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti i have look through it but i am not sure how to use it, can you guide me on how to use that to check the request i am sending?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
email = "blahblah@gmail.com"
token = "abcdefghijk"
url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/request?params1=value1&params2=value2"

uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).start
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, {'email'=>email,'token'=>token})
response = http.request(request)
render json: response.body
```

OR

```
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request.add_field("email", email)
request.add_field("token", token)
response = http.request(request)
render json: response.body
```

Comment: i have tried this and i still get ' {"error":"invalid request parameters"}`. i am not sure why though. Is there any way to check?

Comment: @Edwin - Try this request.add_field("email", email)

Comment: @ vishram0709 it still doesn't work for me. i think that somehow the header isn't added in the request, no matter what i try because it always returns me invalid request parameters.

Comment: @Edwin - Try running on rails console and you might fetch some error. In my PC both these methods worked.

Comment: it still gives the same result. I am not sure whats wrong also. I even tried using the ruby code provided by Postman and it still gives the same error.